# Whether $\sum_{i=1}^k\frac{\prod_{j\neq i}(\alpha_j-\beta)}{\prod_{j\neq i}(\alpha_j-\alpha_i)}=1$ is true

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Suppose we have k positive numbers: $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, ..., \alpha_k$, for any number $\beta>0$, is 
$$\sum_{i=1}^k\frac{\prod_{j\neq i}(\alpha_j-\beta)}{\prod_{j\neq i}(\alpha_j-\alpha_i)}=1$$ 
true? If so, how to prove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the formula for the [Lagrange interpolation polynomial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LagrangeInterpolatingPolynomial.html)
$$L(\beta)=\sum_{i=1}^{k} f_i\prod_{j\neq i}^{k}\frac{\alpha_j-\beta}{\alpha_j-\alpha_i}.\tag{1}$$
This is the unique $(k-1)$th degree polynomial passing through $k$ points
$(\alpha_i,f_i)$, with $i=1,\ldots, k$. In your case all $f_i$'s are equal to $1$, and therefore $L(\beta)=1$.

Comment: Yes. Thank you for the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

The sum is a polynomial with respect to $\beta$. Evaluate the polynomial at the points $\alpha_i$. Use the degree of the polynomial to conclude.

Answer (score 1):

This is a degree $k-1$ polynomial in $\beta$ which is equal to $1$ at the $k$ points $\alpha_1,\ldots, \alpha_k$, and is thus $1$ everywhere.

This follows from the result that a nonzero polynomial of degree $n$ cannot have $n+1$ roots.