# A limit evaluating to $2 K$ (Catalan's constant)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, definite-integrals, catalans-constant

Experimentally I discovered the limit below that says that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{1}{\displaystyle \cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\left(\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)-\cos\left(\frac{x}{2^2}\right)\right)\cdots \left(\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)-\cos\left(\frac{x}{2^{2n+1}}\right)\right)}+\cdots$$
$$+\frac{1}{\displaystyle \cos\left(\frac{x}{2^{2n+1}}\right)\left(\cos\left(\frac{x}{2^{2n+1}}\right)-\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)\cdots \left(\cos\left(\frac{x}{2^{2n+1}}\right)-\cos\left(\frac{x}{2^{2n}}\right)\right)} \ dx=2 K$$

or as @robjohn suggested

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}{\Large\int}_0^{\pi/2}\operatorname*{\Large\sum}_{j=1}^{2n+1}\left[\cos\left(\frac{x}{2^j}\right)\prod_{\substack{k=1\\k\ne j}}^{2n+1}\left(\cos\left(\frac{x}{2^j}\right)-\cos\left(\frac{x}{2^k}\right)\right)\right]^{-1}\mathrm{d}x=2 K$$
Do you see any easy way of proving this result?

Comment: I think I can figure out the pattern of the sum, but it would be nice to explicitly write out what the terms of the products and sum are.

Comment: $$
{\Large\int}_0^{\pi/2} \operatorname*{\Large\sum}_{j=1}^{2n+1}\left[\cos\left(\frac{x}{2^j}\right) \prod_{\substack{k=1\\k\ne j}}^{2n+1}\left(\cos\left(\frac{x}{2^j}\right) -\cos\left(\frac{x}{2^k}\right)\right)\right]^{-1}\mathrm{d}x
$$

Comment: Yes, but the $\lim$ is missing.

Comment: @user153012 yeah, thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Denote $\displaystyle u_j=\cos \frac{x}{2^j}$, and rewrite the integrand as
\begin{align}\sum_j\frac{u_j^{-1}}{\prod_{k\neq j}\left(u_j-u_k\right)}&=\frac{1}{\prod_{m}u_m}
\sum_j \prod_{k\neq j}\frac{0-u_k}{u_j-u_k}=\frac{1}{\prod_{m}u_m},
\end{align} where at the last step we used the Lagrange interpolation formula (see for example the answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/875892/73025)).

The product in the denominator is telescoping: using the double sine formula, we obtain
$$\sin \frac{x}{2^{2n+1}}{\prod_{m}u_m}=\frac{1}{2^{2n+1}}\sin x.$$

Therefore, the limit reduces to
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^{{\pi}/{2}}\frac{2^{2n+1}\sin \frac{x}{2^{2n+1}}}{\sin x}dx=
\int_0^{{\pi}/{2}}\frac{xdx}{\sin x}=2K,$$
where the last equality is essentially the formula (40) from [Wolfram page on Catalan's constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CatalansConstant.html).

Comment: Nicely done (+1)